# Android ListView Like iOS UITableView

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-listview

I want to create a ListView similar to the iOS-component UITableView in Android. I managed to create the sectioned ListView but how do I create an alphabet list on the right?

[image: UITable view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer This library.... Perfect One

https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView

Answer (score 1):

you can create it using the one more List in relative layout .........

Please find the code at

http://hello-android.blogspot.in/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use fast scroll. It is not the same, but similar. Call [`setFastScrollEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled%28boolean%29) on your list view and have your list adapter implement [`SectionIndexer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html).